# Finding largest Integer in array with pointers in assembly 32bit MASM

Tags: arrays, pointers, assembly, masm, 32-bit

I am writing a procedure that finds the largest integer in a array. I have found many examples that are similar but I am confused on how to correctly use the pointers in my procedure. My current output is 41484. I believe this is due to the line [esi+4]. I know it would be much easier to omit the pointers but for the sake of this example I would want to keep things as they are.

Thanks

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
findLargest PROTO, ptrArray:PTR DWORD, ptrCount:PTR DWORD

.data
    array1 DWORD 5,10,15,20,25,30
    array3 DWORD 6,7,4,2
    array4 DWORD -1,2,-5
    theLargest DWORD ?
.code
findLargest PROC uses esi ecx,
    ptrArray: PTR DWORD,;adress of array
    ptrCount:PTR DWORD; size or count of array

    mov esi,ptrArray
    mov ecx,ptrCount

L1:
    cmp esi,ecx
    jl L2

L2:
    cmp [esi+4],edx
    jg L3
    jmp L4
L3: 
        xchg eax,edx
        ret
L4:
    inc esi
    jmp L1

findLargest ENDP

main PROC
    INVOKE findLArgest,
        ADDR array1,
        LENGTHOF array1
    mov theLargest,eax
    call WriteDec
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: [SSE4.1 has `pmaxsd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PMAXSD.html), so if you want this to run fast you could make an SSE4 version using that.  (And an AVX2 version using 32-byte vectors.)

Comment: Your edits invalidated the answer and introduced different bugs (e.g. removing all the loads so your code made no sense anymore, especially not after your last edit which removed everything, so it wasn't clear how it was even supposed to make sense.)  That's why I rolled it back.  Use a debugger to single-step your code and look at register values.